# After setting selectedindex, click on control with mouse shows wrong item

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

The engineers requested a combobox with numbers from 500 to -500 (negative numbers listed at the bottom, so not alphabetical).

They also requested being able to type in the number in the combo to jump to correct item.

Problem: type in "44", tab away. Then click on the control with the mouse and you can see "449" is selected.

Here is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace combotest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 500; i > -500; i--)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

No problem! I tell myself. FindStringExact is finding the first alpha match. So I replace the Leave event code with a loop:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace combotest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 500; i > -500; i--)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void setCombo(string value)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();

            int myindex = -1;
            for (int i = 500; i > -501; i--)
            {
                myindex += 1;

                comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                if (i.ToString().Trim() == value.Trim())
                {
                    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = myindex;
                }
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text);
            setCombo(comboBox1.Text);

        }
    }
}
```

I try it again and still when I click the mouse on the combo after typing in "44" and tabbing away, "449" is selected instead.

Comment: Why aren't you using [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way you're populating the `ComboBox`, 449 occurs earlier in the list than 44, and so it's selected first (it's the first closest match to what the user is typing). To get the desired behavior, you'd have to have two lists - one that goes from 0 to 500 and another that goes from 0 to -500.

Instead, use a `NumericUpDown` box and set the `Maximum` property to 500 and the `Minimum` value to -500. That will ensure the user can only enter a number that falls within the specified range.

Answer (score 0):

I simply suggest

1. Enable AutoComplete Source to True
2. Then add the same Items you added in combobox to AutoComplete Source
3. Set the AutoComplete Mode to "SuggestAppend".
4. Set the Value of Combobox to SelectedItem.

I don't recommend using index.